# jQuery UI Custom CSS Scope .dialog() Quirks

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've got a scenario where a third party app is using jqUI. So for my customizations I wish to use another version and have provided a custom CSS scope. With .dialog() jqUI moves the target outside of my custom scope for the absolute positioning/overlay. Here's a workaround:

```
// custom jQ namespace
var d = my.jq('#my-modal').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false});
d.parent('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="my-part"></div>');
d.dialog('open');
```

However this now breaks the overlay shadowing. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. The overlay is just very faint with the smoothness theme that I didn't notice. Who wants an answer?

Comment: What about you ? Post your answer and accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought this wasn't an issue any longer but it actually is. Here's a workaround:

```
// custom jQ namespace
var d = my.jq('#my-modal').dialog({ 
  modal: true, 
  autoOpen: false, 
  'open': function () { my.jq('.ui-widget-overlay').wrap('<div class="my-part"></div>'); }
});
d.parent('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="my-part"></div>');
d.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery UI 1.10.2, the only way I could get the modal dialog to work CCS Scope is to wrap both the dialog and overlay in the "open" event like below:

```
open: function () {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').each(function () {
        $(this).next('.ui-dialog').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="CSSScopeClass" />');
    });
}
```

The only thing that does not seem to work with this approach is having "width" set to "auto".  I also had to set the dialog width manually.

Comment: Like a boss!  jqueryui 1.10.3 - don't forget to remove the wrapper div from the DOM when the dialog is closed

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer is a late but this issue turned up for me when I was trying to find a similar answer by searching in Google so thought I'd include this in case it helps anyone on a similar search:

```
    $('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="abc" />');
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').wrap('<div class="abc" />');
```

Where `abc` is the name of your 'CSS wrapper' - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199888/custom-css-scope-jquery-ui-dialog-themes) where I found the answer from [Evgeni Nabokov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549531/evgeni-nabokov). For more info on CSS wrapper in use with JQueru UI dialog box - see the following (but note it doesn't solve the issue of the CSS wrapper WITH THE DIALOG BOX - you need the above comments to help there: [Filament blog](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/))