# Controlling the DOM location of a jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to create a jQueryUI Dialog and have it insert itself into the dom within a specific element.  We have a content section that is the parent of a number of styles so items within the dialog are not styled since jqueryUI does an append to body.  Is there a way to tell jqueryUI to append to a selector of my choosing?

What it does

```
<section id="content">
</section>
<div class="dialog"> the dialog </div>
```

what I want

```
<section id="content">
<div class="dialog"> the dialog </div>
</section>
```

Comment: $(".selector").dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" }); is what you are looking for...see my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this question is a little old but I wanted to make sure any new comers were pointed in the right direction. The option "appendTo" was added in version 1.10.0.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" });
```

You can read about it [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo)

Comment: Very neat solution you saved me a lot of possble code refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

From [Custom CSS scope and jQuery UI dialog themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199888/custom-css-scope-jquery-ui-dialog-themes)

```
// Create the dialog, but don't open it yet
var d = $('#myDialogContents').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
    // other dialog options
});
// Take whole dialog and put it back into the custom scope
d.parent('.ui-dialog').appendTo('.myCustomScope');
// Open the dialog (if you want autoOpen)
d.dialog('open');
```

Comment: Note that if the `.myCustomScope` has `overflow:` set to auto, hidden, or scroll, the dialog box will be affected since it's a child of that element.

Comment: Going to accept the more recent answer as it's now a better solution

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#options) maybe of some use.
But the thing you'd like to achieve seems to me a bit against the model of jQuery UI library. You can style the dialog using the CSS classes specified in the Theme tab on [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).
If you can transfer the id of the element, you want to make into a dialog, to a class, you can use the following code

```
$( ".dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'content' });
```

and you should update your CSS to reflect the change. Thus you do not introduce duplicate id-s (which may lead to problems in future work and is semantically incorrect), if you duplicate the `#content` tag inside the dialog content

Comment: it's not the dialog I want to style, it's the form fields, sections, labels, fieldsets etc within the dialog that I want to style and right now they are set like so  #content fieldset label {styles} but since jqueryUI appends the dom element it creates to body it's no longer "under" #content and the styles don't cascade properly

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, you can change `#content` to `.ui-dialog-content` and this will work. If there are fieldsets in #content, which should be styled the same way as these shown in the dialog, you can always do something like `#content fieldset label, .ui-dialog-content fieldset label {styles}`

Comment: all in all there are about 30 or 40 styles that cascade from #content and I'd rather not have to repeat everything to also nest under .ui-dialog-content like this ",.ui-dialog-content form fieldset section input" etc

Comment: in regards to my question though, is it possible to have jquery append to a specific dom element other than body

Comment: yes, that's nasty. The only optimization I can think of is if you can omit the `#content` part of the expression - this may help.

Comment: An excerpt from the source code of jQueryUI dialog: `uiDialog = (self.uiDialog = $('<div></div>')).appendTo(document.body)`

Comment: i'll leave this open for now.  My quick hack is to duplicate the #content id inside the dialog content.  Nothing we do uses #content as a selector so it shouldn't really hurt anything

Comment: If you convert id to class you can use this: `$( ".dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'content' });` The replacement in your text editor in the css from id to class should be trivial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199888/custom-css-scope-jquery-ui-dialog-themes this pretty much gives me the functionality i needed

Comment: nice and simple workaround in case of a single dialog on the page. Voted it up :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery's [**append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
$('#content').append('<div class="dialog"> the dialog </div>');
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on here.  when you call $('#mydialog').dialog() jquery clones your content to build a new div then appends that to 'body' thus breaking the cascade

Comment: If that's what you want, you could store a reference to the previous parent of the dialog when you create the dialog, and move the dialog back on close.

Comment: it's not about when the dialog closes, it's the fact that it's got the wrong parent when it opens.