# Is there way to connect css and UI custom class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, css, ios

It's very interested is there way to connect CSS styles and UI custom class. For example create class what inherited UIButton class and add CSS styles to them. Is it possible?

**EDIT**
My css:

```
.button {
   border: 3px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   padding: 20px 40px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
   color: #06426c;
   font-size: 9px;
   font-family: helvetica, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
   border: 3px solid #0a3c59;
   text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   color: #fff;
}
.button:active {
  text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
  border: 3px solid #0a3c59;
  background: #65a9d7;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#3e779d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d 0%, #65a9d7 100%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

And my class is inherited from UIButton class without any other changes. I want only add css properties.

Comment: yes it's possible you can change/add new css property, but little complicated, make sure that no JavaScript effected if added...

Comment: can you give me some example or link to some tutorial?

Comment: check this question, i think this may helpful for you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308369/jquery-ui-dialog-individual-css-styling

Comment: @K.K I don't see how can I add css to my class..

Comment: can you put here your CSS and UI custom class so that i can explain...

Answer (score 0):

It Should work.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    // add your own class
    jQuery(".button").addClass("ui-button-new-css");

    jQuery(".button.ui-button-new-css").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("ui-button-new-css-hover");
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-button-new-css-hover");
    });

    jQuery(".button.ui-button-new-css").focus(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("ui-button-new-css-active");
    });

    jQuery(".button.ui-button-new-css").blur(function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-button-new-css-active");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
    .button.ui-button-new-css { 
        /* your new css property */
    }
    .button.ui-button-new-css.ui-button-new-css-hover { 
        /* your new hover css property */
    }
    .button.ui-button-new-css.ui-button-new-css-active { 
        /* your new active css property */
    }
</style>
```