# jQuery UI Dialog border not working in 1.12.1 anymore

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, border

Up to now I used jQuery UI 1.11.4, and within my web application I display some Dialog Widgets for several actions, informations and so on. I forced them to have a thin blue border using the following CSS style, which worked fine:

```
.ui-dialog {
  border: 2px solid #0000FF;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Now today, I switched to jQuery UI 1.12.1, and the border isn't shown anymore... I analyzed the differences between the 1.11.4 and the 1.12.1 Dialog, and the only main difference I saw was that the old version had an additional

```
display: block;
```

in its style, and so I tried to add this to my own style. No effect... The border had disappeared.

Of course I made an research about my problem first before asking - without success... The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308369/jquery-ui-dialog-individual-css-styling) didn't work, too.

Has anybody an idea about that issue?

Comment: I can surely help, but I need to be able to inspect. Either reproduce your problem here using minimal required code or provide a link outlining a clear set of instructions on where exactly is what you are talking about in your page. Regards,

Comment: Hi Andrei, I will try to set up two simple example pages, one using jQuery UI 1.11.4 and the other one using 1.12.1. I hope I can reproduce the issue there and I will send you the links. However, I won't have the time to do that until Monday. Thanks in advance to you for having a look, and a nice weekned!

Comment: There's no need for both, as long as I understand what you're after. This is a minor issue, but I wanted to clear out any back and forths due to misunderstanding. Normally a link to the 1.12.1 version will suffice.I'll ask for details if it doesn't. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their examples page, this should do it, as long as your `css` is loaded after `jquery-ui.css`:

```
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: 2px solid #0000FF;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If your custom stylesheet is loaded before `jquery-ui.css` (which would be wrong - it should be the last stylesheet loaded in page, so you could easily override existing CSS using the selectors of same specificity) you'll need a slightly stronger selector: `div.ui-widget.ui-widget-content`.

This only applies if you haven't customized the default markup of `jquery-ui` widgets and you don't have other snippets of code with stronger selectors affecting the elements we're trying to style.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved!. Of course I loaded my own css after the jQueryUI css, but the selector `.ui-dialog` that I used really seems to be not strong enough to display the border in jQuery UI 1.12.1 (in 1.11.4 this worked). `.ui-widget.ui-widget-content` did the job.