# Styling jQuery UI Dialog Heading?

Tags: css

I know how to style the content of dialogs independently of one another by appending a class to the div and then referencing both classes in the CSS `.ui-dialog.myClass{}`. What I want to do is style the headers of the dialogs independently of one another and I just can't seem to make it work.

```
.ui-widget-header.error-dialog{
background: red;
}

.ui-widget-header.success-dialog{
background: green;
}
```

so on and so forth... Appending the class attached to the div of the dialog of interest doesn't seem to do the job.

```
<div id="error-dialog" class="error-dialog" title="ERROR"></div>
<div id="success-dialog" class ="success-dialog" title="SUCCESS">
    <p>Habitat classification completed successfully! Your results will be viewable in 10 minutes.</p>
</div>
```

For example, I'm trying to change the background color of the gray bar that contains ERROR, it is possible I'm just not using the right UI CSS classes:
[image]

This is what the HTML looks like when I inspect the element, I have a feeling I'm just not styling the right classes. The div highlighted in blue is where the header color is controlled. All classes listed are automatically assigned to the dialog, I have not edited any of them. If you do edit them, it will affect all dialogs, not just the specific dialog I want.
[image]

Comment: Your div's don't have the class `ui-widget-header` ?

Comment: @Akshay - I've added that class in my various iterations of testing. It doesn't do anything. The .ui-widget-header is automatically assigned to the dialog upon initialization, somehow I need to customize it for each one.

Comment: where do you include those styles? before or after the default jquery ui styles?  Also if you inspect the element, do you see those styles applied but crossed out?

Comment: @Pete After. I load jquery-us.css, jquery-ui.smoothness.min.css, then I load my custom styles. I do not see the styles applied.

Comment: Ok what about if you inspect the element?

Comment: @Pete the styles aren't applied at all. I added a new picture to the bottom of my original post that might be of help.

Comment: Seems like the one you inspect doesn't have any of the original classes on.  The one below has the error class on - perhaps it hasn't errored or been successful?

Comment: @Pete - yup, that's the problem. The dataset I'm running purposely causes an error so the error dialog will show up, so it has errored. The problem I see with jQuery UI is that it only assigns my custom class to the content of the dialog rather than the header. I found this thread that also describes this issue, I'm going to see if any of those fixes will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308369/jquery-ui-dialog-individual-css-styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had my classes mixed around and implemented the dialogClass option when instantiating a dialog instead of specifically put the custom class in the HTML. It is worth noting that dialog*Class* is a bit of a misnomer as when you set that option, you're actually putting the id of your target dialog, not a class. This appears to work how I want it to.

HTML:

```
<div id="error-dialog" title="ERROR"></div>
<div id="success-dialog" title="SUCCESS">
    <p>Habitat classification completed successfully! Your results will be viewable in 10 minutes.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var errorDialog = $("#error-dialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: "auto",
              width: 1000,
              modal: true,
              dialogClass: 'error-dialog',
              buttons: [{
                  id: "error-ok",
                  text: "Ok",
                  click: function () {
                      errorDialog.dialog("close");
                  }
              }]
          });

      var successDialog = $('#success-dialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 200,
          width: 400,
          modal: true,
          dialogClass: 'success-dialog',
          buttons: [{
              id: "success-ok",
              text: "Ok",
              click: function () {
                  successDialog.dialog("close");
              }
          }]
      });
```

CSS:

```
.error-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
}

.success-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need the `.ui-widget-header`.
Basically whatever you have as your class you put in front of your css with a . in front in your example it would be:

```
.error-dialog{
background: red;
}

.success-dialog{
background: green;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9acb42v8/

Comment: @AndrewG - have you used jQuery UI dialogs before? Styling them is not that simple. UI appends a bunch of classes to the dialog automatically and it appears that any custom class I assign to the dialog only gets assigned to the content, not the header. I want to change the titlebar/header background color, not the content background color.